# Making dairy free using coconut cream with low fat white chocolate Ganache

Tags: ganache

I am trying to make white chocolate ganache dairy free using coconut cream. Dont know fat %. I cant get it to thicken. I am using Callebaut white chocolate for the first time. I have made dairy free dark choc ganache using coconut cream and bakers chocolate and it sets always. But I cannot get my white choc ganache to set. it has been in the fridge 5 - 6 hours.

Comment: Do Callebaut make a dairy-free white? I  haven't seen it (they make dairy-free dark and have recently launched a dairy-free milk-like product). If so what are it's ingredients?

Comment: Hello CharH, at a first glance, there is no reason for a coconut ganache to behave differently from a dairy ganache, while using dark ganache proportions with white ganache is a very common mistake. So I'm closing it as a duplicate of a question for standard white ganache. If you really used a white ganache recipe with the proper tiny ratio of cream, please edit this into the question (including the exact ratio) and we can reopen.